# Finding PI Value using "Dart Board Method"

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to find the value of PI using the "Dart Board Method" but I've been unable to find a relevant algorithm on the net. Do you know of a link which can help me to understand this method and also provides an algorithm for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, could you tag it as such and give more details about what's expected of you and what language you're using? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is homework, I am using C.

Comment: Here's a simple explanation and visualization with a JavaScript(ish) implementation: https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/probabilistic-pi-and-tau-approximation/4784413679550464

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i have found the solution here, it present the code and also help me to understand it better, basically i was also confused on how to know if this is within circle lox I have to work on my math!

http://books.google.com/books?id=JlG5rFH7Ge0C&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=Dartboard+Method+algorithm&source=bl&ots=t76R30Q342&sig=NjguOYMc0ILqZs8Bcz6uIpfejdc&hl=en&ei=-YzTSuutFMefkQXj9_H7Aw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CCIQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=&f=false

Answer (score 12):

Summary: consider a 1x1 square. Its area is 1.

Consider a circle which fits just inside the square. Its area is `pi * r * r`, which is `pi / 4`.

So, if you throw a squillion darts at that square (and they all hit, and their x and y co-ordinates each have independent uniform distribution), then for any subset of that square, you'd expect the proportion of the darts inside it to be equal to the area of the subset as a proportion of the area of the square.

So count how many darts fall inside the circle (by measuring whether the distance from the dart to the centre of the square is greater than or less than 1/2), divide by a squillion, multiply by 4, and you have a Monte Carlo estimate of pi.

Answer (score 4):

For a start maybe the more known name helps you

[Monte Carlo Integration (aka DartBoard Method)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_Integration)

Answer (score 1):

These links may help you with the solution to your problem:

http://people.bu.edu/balarsen/Home/IDL/Entries/2008/2/8_Monte_Carlo_Integration_%28dartboard_method%29.html

http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/MonteCarloPiMod.html

Answer (score 0):

Great video on the subject here...

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/video-lectures/lecture-20/

Move to minute 30:36 for the section on estimating Pi.