# Octave approximation of e

Tags: octave, mcmc

I want to use MCMC algorithm in Octave to calculate with max precision the following expression: "1/e". After reading some tutorials I found a formula for calculating π, but I do not understand how it works.

```
octave:2> S=1e7; a=rand(S,2); 4*mean(sum(a.*a,2)<1)
ans = 3.1418
```

Can someone maybe explain and help me with a hint, how to use such thing for calculating the  value of 'e'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is an application of [the dartboard method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556518/finding-pi-value-using-dart-board-method) for estimating pi. Essentially you are creating an Sx2 matrix (think of it as S number of (x,y) coordinates) all with values between 0 and 1, so geometrically within a 1x1 square. You are then squaring the x and y values and adding them to get the distance squared of the point from the origin. `<1` will translate all of these distances into either a 0 or a 1 depending on whether the point lies within the quarter circle of radius one centered at the origin. The mean of this binary array is the ratio of "darts" that hit within the quarter circle out of the total thrown, which is an approximation of its area. Multiply by 4, and you have an estimate for the full circle of radius 1, whose exact area is equal to pi.

Doing a google search brings up this (hopefully) useful publication for calculating e in a similar manner: [Monte Carlo estimations of e](http://caos.fs.usb.ve/~srojas/Teaching/USB/MC_Intro/MC_readings_a/MC_a1_computing_e.pdf)